# Add controls dynamic using ajax

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajax, telerik

I have a search button in a asp.net page that show a pop-up and by closing that some controls are be added to a panel in my form using AjaxManager of Telerik.
I've used the Telerik:AjaxUpdatedControl to say render the panel everytime a search is done.
But my proble is when search is done for second time the controls that had been adde for first time will be removed.
how can I overcome this problem?

Comment: Would you be able to post some code about how you are going about this? Keep in mind that depending on how you are adding the items you might have to do add them to the page for every single search - not just the first one.

Answer (score 1):

Dynamic controls are not created after a postback. You have to recreate them every single time. (Their viewstate is still maintained you just have to create them with the same ID and in the same place within the control hierarchy).

The DynamicControlsPlaceholder control does this all for you. It is available at - http://www.denisbauer.com/ASPNETControls/DynamicControlsPlaceholder.aspx

However I would suggest you use it for as little as possible. Heavy usage of it can cause performance to suffer.